# Notice: Undefined index: user-report-block in dashboard_page_build() (line 192 of /home/mysite/public_html/modules/dashboard/dashboard.module)

Tags: 7, views

I added a couple of user Views in my Drupal 7 site and enabled the blocks on the dashboard.

I am now getting the below error messages:

```
Notice: Undefined index: user-report-block in dashboard_page_build() (line 192 of /home/mysite/public_html/modules/dashboard/dashboard.module).
Notice: Undefined index: user-report-block--2 in dashboard_page_build() (line 192 of /home/mysite/public_html/modules/dashboard/dashboard.module).
```

Why might this be the case, and how do I get rid of the error messages?

I tried disabling all the blocks from the dashboard, clearing the cache, and doing an update.php did nothing; the error messages are still shown.

Comment: This has been discussed on https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/936798. There is a working patch on that page.